# Когда надо использовать instanceof в Java?

Tags: java

Не могу понять зачем нужно это ключевое слово. Объясните на примере, пожалуйста.

Допустим, у меня есть метод, в который можно передать объект любого типа.

```
void foo(Object o){
//?
}
```

И я хочу проверить к какому типу относится объект. Наверное, я не правильно понял суть `instanceof`. Но, все же напишу как считаю

```
if(o instanceof Integer){
//Your logic
}
```

Если понял правильно, то объясните, можно ли воспользоваться `instanceof` для развлетвения `switch/case`?

Также если понял верно, объясните пожалуйста, зачем он нужен, если можно создать несколько методов для разной логики?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Всё просто: `o instanceof Integer` просто проверяет, является ли реальный тип объекта `o` типом `Integer`.

Вы и правда можете создать несколько методов для вашей логики, один для `Integer`, другой для `String`. Но если к вам приходит `Object`, вы не сможете вызвать нужный метод, потому что *не знаете*, какого реально типа ваш объект. Вот для того, чтобы это выяснить, и нужен `instanceof`.

Кстати, использовать конструкцию `switch` с `instanceof` не выйдет, `switch` требует примитивные типы или `String`*. Но вы можете написать цепочку `if`'ов:

```
if (x instanceof Integer) {
    // что-то сделать с (Integer)x
} else if (x instanceof String) {
    // что-то сделать с (String)x
} else {
    // ну не шмагла я определить тип
}
```

---

В правильной, хорошо написанной программе, количество `instanceof` и подобых конструкций обычно невелико: имеет смысл избегать передачи нетипизированных объектов (например, параметров типа `Object`), а там, где код должен работать с параметрами различного типа, использовать дженерики. Однако иногда приходится пользоваться подходом с `instanceof`, например, при взаимодействии с API, которое было написано ещё до прихода дженериков.

---

Ещё по теме:

- [Расширение и сужение типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/167311/10105).
- [Причины использования DownCast](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432197/10105)

---

*Или `enum`, или врапперы на примитивные типы наподобие `Character`.

Comment: `switch требует примитивные типы` – а как же `String`?

Comment: @post_zeew: И правда. Дописал уточнение.

Comment: Я, кстати, про оболочки специально не стал писать, так как, насколько я понимаю, в `switch` происходит их автораспаковка, поэтому Ваше выражение для них справедливо :)

Comment: @post_zeew: Но энумы наверное важны. Потому что энум у Java больше, чем энум.