# Какая разница между Parent child = new Child() и Child child = new Child()?

Tags: java

Ответа в гугле внятного не нашел. Увидел разницу лишь в том, что child типа Parent не может обратится к методу который есть в классе наследнике Child. Тогда какой смысл такой конструкции:
Parent child = new Child(). Для чего это может пригодится?
Заранее спасибо! )^-^)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166875/Расширение-и-сужение-типов

Comment: в приведенном вами примере смысла нет. но могу вам сказать абсолютно точно, что вам нужно разобраться с тем, что такое полиморфизм. понимание этого в итоге и будет ответом на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

1. Как заметил Дмитрий в комментарии

> в приведенном вами примере смысла нет. но могу вам сказать абсолютно
> точно, что вам нужно разобраться с тем, что такое полиморфизм.
> понимание этого в итоге и будет ответом на ваш вопрос. –  Дмитрий

2. `parent child = new child();` и `child child = new child();`
   Если всё ок, то по большей части тут работа с метода.
   В такой конструкции `parent child = new child();` - сможете пользоваться только методами из класс `parent` , а при такой конструкции `child child = new child();` - методами класса `child` и `parent`

Лично я так это вижу если вкратце.